# Content with HEXAGON EFFECT

Tags: html, css

I wanna create information content with hexagon effect [image]

It's my code:

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 270px; 
  height: 155.88px;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 82px;
}
/*.hexagon:nth-child(8n) {
 margin-left: 140px;
}*/

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 135px solid transparent;
  border-right: 135px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 77.94px solid #64C7CC;
}

.hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 77.94px solid #64C7CC;
}
.hexagon:first-child {
 margin-left: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon" style="margin-left: 140px;"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon" style="margin-left: 140px;"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon" style="margin-left: 140px;"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
       <div class="hexagon"></div>
```

1-Problem: How write in class `hexagon` pseudoclass `nth-child` for change instead of an attribute `(margin-left:140px)`.. I need `margin-left` in each of the eight class

2-Problem: How this hexagon to do adaptive.. no difference even if do with `@media`

Answer (score -1):

If the final goal is the picture in your question I would go another way.
I would use an image with a transparent part in the shape if a hexagon in the middle and the rest is in background color. **Behind** this image I would put the actual image, this a unit. Then i would overlap these units.

Does this makes scene to U?

Comment: When i Fix First problem, when i must do each eight class hexagon write margin-left... later i add another block with hexagon, and do this `opacity:0` and when user hover i do `opacity:1`.. it's simple.. but i don't know how do this effect do adaptive.. i add image into the class `hexagon` and will write `overflow: hidden;`
P.S. sorry for my english =)